# Getting No bean named 'jobLauncher' available exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, spring-batch, job-scheduling

Application started but got this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'jobLauncher' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at com.hms.ar.batch.job.ARBatchJobApplication.main(ARBatchJobApplication.java:55)
```

I have tried creating spring.xml under resources folder
 and defined JobLauncher bean. still got same exception

I have tried to @Autowire this bean. Still got same exception

some of the codes in my main mathod

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        savedArgs = args;
        String jobName = processParameters(args);
        ApplicationContext ctx = configureApplication(new SpringApplicationBuilder()).run(args);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) ctx.getBean("jobLauncher");
        JobExplorer jobExplorer = (JobExplorer) ctx.getBean("jobExplorer");
        Job job = (Job) ctx.getBean(jobName);

}
```

I expected my job to start but it's not starting because of this exception

Comment: where do you define the bean?

Comment: Show the code for JobLauncher

Comment: I imported JobLauncher from org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher . i did not define it any where else

Answer (score 3):

Add @EnableBatchProcessing to one of your config classes.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureJob.html

> The @EnableBatchProcessing works similarly to the other @Enable* annotations in the Spring family. In this case, @EnableBatchProcessing provides a base configuration for building batch jobs. Within this base configuration, an instance of StepScope is created in addition to a number of beans made available to be autowired:
>
> - JobRepository - bean name "jobRepository"
> - JobLauncher - bean name "jobLauncher"
> - JobRegistry - bean name "jobRegistry"
> - PlatformTransactionManager - bean name "transactionManager"
> - JobBuilderFactory - bean name "jobBuilders"
> - StepBuilderFactory - bean name "stepBuilders"

Comment: Thank you. It resolved this exceptions no bean named JobLauncher, JobExplorer and Jjob found.. now I'm getting no bean named myClass available.

Comment: You havent showed myClass in your code. Have you registered it as a spring-managed component?